# IPhone link error using LLVM 2.0 based on XCode 4.0.1

Tags: xcode4, llvm

Meet the following link error using LLVM 2.0 based on XCode 4.0.1, I don't know what does it mean and how to fix it?  please help, any idea or discussion will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

ld: bad codegen, pointer diff in ___cxx_global_var_init79 to global weak symbol __ZN5boost16exception_detail23exception_ptr_bad_allocILi42EE1eE for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1

ENV:
yuma:MyApp yujianhuayu$ clang -v
Apple clang version 2.0 (tags/Apple/clang-138) (based on LLVM 2.9svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10
Thread model: posix

BTW:
Seems link well for simulator but bad for device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with the build setting options "Generate Position-dependent code" and "Symbols hidden by default"

Setting this last one to YES usually solves this issue.

If not check if all your projects files & link libraries are compiled also with this version of LLVM.

I would also advise you to use the latest version of XCode.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, how does these options mean? How do you know why change this can solve the problem? Could you provide more info?  Thanks very much.